# What is the positive statement of the question "Whose frying pan is this?"

Tags: interrogatives, transformation

What is the positive statement of the question "Whose frying pan is this?"

I mean How can I transform from question to the positive statement. What would it look like? I hope I explain myself understandably.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to transform it into a sentence like "I wonder who is the owner of this frying pan"? That is, into a sentence without the question sign?

Answer (score 4):

I believe such a statement is called "*declarative*", not "*positive*" (that is, it could be *negative* too, and still *declarative*).

CopperKettle's example

> I wonder who is the owner of this frying pan.

is of course fine, and a more strict example would be

> I want to know whose frying pan *this is*.

Note the change in the order between "**this**" and "**is**".